# Can't access variable from another class python

Tags: python, object, instance-variables

Here is my code which is supposed to print self.cake and self.age from the class Settings.

```
from startup import Settings
class Profile(Settings):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Profile, self).__init__()

    def print_settings(self):
        print self.cake
        print self.age

p = Profile()
p. print_settings()
```

Other python script

```
class Settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cake = 1

    def number(self):
        self.age = 5
```

But I keep getting:

```
AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'age'
```

I need to be able to print the variables from the print_settings function.

What should I do?

Comment: add `self.cake` and `self.age` to `__init__` function

Comment: no I can't do that, they have to be separate

Comment: What you mean by "they have to be seperate" ?

Comment: self.cake needs to be in the __init__  function and self.age needs to be in the number function

Comment: define it as `self.age=None` in `__init__` function

Comment: that sort of works but this example is just a simple version of the code i am writing and in my code i would have to write None for each variable and that is not good

Comment: There's no way around that.  If you want the variable to exist, you have to assign it a value before you use it.  You can either do that all in one place (in `__init__`) or you'll force consumers of your class to define them all themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `age` attribute before calling the `print_settings` method.

One option would be:

```
p = Profile()
p.number()
p.print_settings()
```